# Using bool type conversion operator and Comparison operator overload methods in the same file

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, boolean-operations

I'm trying to do a code, but every time I ran it, it uses the wrong operator:

```
class Date {
   private:
      int m_year;
      int m_mon;
      int m_day;
      int m_ErrorCode;
      int m_CUR_YEAR;
      int daysSince0001_1_1()const; // returns number of days passed since the date 0001/1/1
      bool validate();             /* validates the date setting the error code and then returning the result 
                                    true, if valid, and false if invalid.*/
      void errCode(int);           // sets the error code
      int systemYear()const;       // returns the current system year
      bool bad()const;             // return true if
      int mdays()const;            // returns the number of days in current month
      void setToToday();           // sets the date to the current date (system date)
   public:
      Date();                      // creates a date with current date
      Date(int year, int mon, int day); /* create a date with assigned values
                                         then validates the date and sets the 
                                         error code accordingly */
      int errCode()const;         // returns the error code or zero if date is valid
      const char* dateStatus()const;  // returns a string corresponding the current status of the date
      int currentYear()const;         // returns the m_CUR_YEAR value;

      bool operator==(Date& date) const;
      bool operator!=(Date& date) const;
      bool operator>=(Date& date) const;
      bool operator<=(Date& date) const;
      bool operator<(Date& date) const;
      bool operator>(Date& date) const;

      int operator-(Date& date) const;

      operator bool() const;

      std::istream& read(std::istream& is = std::cin);
      std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os = std::cout)const;

      
   };
```

This is my class module

```
 bool Date::bad()const {
        return m_ErrorCode != 0;
    }

    bool Date::operator==(Date& date) const {
        return daysSince0001_1_1() == date.daysSince0001_1_1();
    }
    bool Date::operator!=(Date& date) const {
        return daysSince0001_1_1() != date.daysSince0001_1_1();
    }
    bool Date::operator>=(Date& date) const {
        return daysSince0001_1_1() >= date.daysSince0001_1_1();
    }
    bool Date::operator<=(Date& date) const {
        return daysSince0001_1_1() <= date.daysSince0001_1_1();
    }
    bool Date::operator<(Date& date) const {
        return daysSince0001_1_1() < date.daysSince0001_1_1();
    }
    bool Date::operator>(Date& date) const {
        return daysSince0001_1_1() > date.daysSince0001_1_1();
    }

    int Date::operator-(Date& date) const {
        return daysSince0001_1_1() - date.daysSince0001_1_1();
    }

    Date::operator bool() const {
        return !bad();
    }
```

And this is part of my implementations.
However, if I do this:

```
if (B > A) {
        cout << B << " > " << A << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << B << " <= " << A << endl;
    }
    if (B < A) {
        cout << B << " < " << A << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << B << " >= " << A << endl;
    }
    if (B <= A) {
        cout << B << " <= " << A << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << B << " > " << A << endl;
    }
    if (B >= A) {
        cout << B << " >= " << A << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << B << " < " << A << endl;
    }
    if (B == A) {
        cout << B << " == " << A << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << B << " != " << A << endl;
    }
    if (B != A) {
        cout << B << " != " << A << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << B << " == " << A << endl;
    }
    cout << "Days between the two dates: " << B - A << endl;
```

It uses the operator bool() const instead of the right function

I already tried using chatgpt and reading about the overload methods, but it didn't change

Comment: It's hard to tell without a full [MCVE], but consider marking the arguments to your comparison functions as `const`. E.g., `bool operator==(const Date& date) const;`

Comment: The parameter `Date& date` tells me "This is an alias to the caller's argument, and this routine **will change the value of the caller's argument**".  Did you intend `Date const& date`?

Comment: Side note: Provided you have C++20 available then instead of implementing all those comparison operators you could simply have implemented the spaceship operator: `std::strong_ordering operator<=>(Date const& other) { return daysSince0001_1_1() <=> date.daysSince0001_1_1(); }`

Comment: "It uses the operator bool() const instead of the right function" what is "it" ? and what is "the right function" ? How do you know `operator bool` is called?

Comment: even without c++20 you can implement all comparison in terms of `<` and `==`

Comment: @Eljay *'[...] will* [potentially] *change [...]'* to be fully precise, but yes ;)